# how do i get my dice game to stop giving me errors when using random numbers

Tags: python

it keeps giving me syntax errors in the highlighted areas please could someone tell me why i get them. [this image shows you the code that i have used and highlighted areas where i get a syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSrAw.png)

if the link doesn't work here is the code without the highlighted areas:

```
goes = 3
while True:
    import random
    die1 = 0
    die2 = 0
    die3 = 0
    die1 = str(random.randint(1,6))
    die2 = str(random.randint(1,6))
    die3 = str(random.randint(1,6))

    if die1 == die2 == die3:
        print(die1+die2+die3)

    if die1 == die2 not die3:
        print(die1+die2-die3)

    if die1 == die3 not die2:
        print(die1+die3-die2)

    if die2 == die3 not die1:
        print(die2+die3-die1)

    else:
        print(0)
    goes=goes-1
    if goes < 1:
        break

    print ([die1],[die2],[die3])
```

Comment: What do you mean by `die1 == die2 not die3`?

Comment: Probably you want `!=` instead of `not`.

Comment: also confused as to why you made your numbers strings... lol

Comment: I want to add that your import statement should be at the top. Putting it inside a loop is not a good idea. It only needs to be imported once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`die1 == die2 not die3` doesn't meant anything. I assume you meant:

```
die1 == die2 and not (die1 == die3)
```

or more simply:

```
die1 == die2 and die1 != die3
```

Since we've already checked if all three are equal, we can avoid the later comparisons anyway by using `elif`:

```
if die1 == die2 == die3:
    print(die1+die2+die3)
elif die1 == die2:
    print(die1+die2-die3)
elif die1 == die3:
    print(die1+die3-die2)
elif die2 == die3:
    print(die2+die3-die1)
```

So if the code reaches `elif die1 == die2:` that means that `die1 == die2 == die3` was false.

Comment: Note that `dieX - dieY` will only work on numerics, not on strings.